# How to move around searchResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I suppose I want to move them to place that I like best. I can set the frame, but where should I set that?

Also how do I ensure that the table still show up irrelevant of whether search result is empty or not?

This is what I have tried:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    controller.searchResultsTableView.frame=self.placeForTableView.frame;
    controller.searchResultsTableView.hidden=false;
    controller.searchResultsTableView.alpha =1;
    [self debugMode:nil];
    return true;
}
```

Result:

1. When text is searchResultsTableView is still empty
2. When there is one character, the frame is not moved yet
3. When there are more than 2 characters, things work as I wish.

Then I added things like this:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [self putTableViewWhereItBelongs:tableView];
}
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [self putTableViewWhereItBelongs:tableView];
}
-(void)putTableViewWhereItBelongs :(UITableView *) tableView
{
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    tableView.frame=self.placeForTableView.frame;
    tableView.hidden=false;
    tableView.alpha =1;
}
```

This works EXACTLY as I wish with one small catch. At the very beginning it doesn't work. At the very beginning the tableView is neither shown or hidden.

Another Update:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    //UISearchDisplayController * controller = [self displayControllerForThisSearchBar:searchBar];
    if (IsEmpty(searchBar.text)) {
        searchBar.text=@" ";
        searchBar.text=@"";
    }

    //[self putTableViewWhereItBelongs:controller.searchResultsTableView];
}
```

Problem:

1. Awkward
2. A short glitch. I don't want this to be animated. I don't want my user to even know I have this problem. Well it does look a little animated for less than 1 second

Otherwise the final result is exactly as I please.

I wonder if anyone can improve this.

Comment: Try postponing the call to putTableViewWhereItBelongs to the next run loop cycle, with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay